# Windows Store App Name

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

Can two Windows Store Apps have same name?
When I tried to reserve a name for my app, I found that it has already been reserved. Is this the name for my app which is displayed in the Windows Store?
Can my app package name and the app name be different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694077.aspx) you can find the information, you're looking for:

Two apps in Windows Store can't share the same name:

> Each name that you reserve must be unique throughout the entire Store, not just in a particular language.

You are reserving the `DisplayName` for your app:

> When you submit your app to the Windows Store, the Package/Properties/DisplayName value must match the name that you reserved for your app in the Dashboard.

I'm not sure what you're refering to with "package name". The package `Identity` does not match the `DisplayName` but is created for you:

> Before you can submit your app to the Windows Store, your app must also define the Name attribute of the Package/Identity element in the app manifest. This must be the package identity name that the Windows Store created for your app.

Answer (score 0):

No, they can not submit it. It is a good practice to reserve a name for your app in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

you can't share the same name,because it always unique .
But alternative you can try like "Windows App" as "Windows_app".
It helps a lot.